# UPDATE SQL table with WHERE to other table

Tags: sql, sqlite

I'm currently trying to figure out how to UPDATE rows in a table when a qualifier from another table applies. E.g., "SET x to y WHERE A.z = B.z AND B.x = 'foo'".

Based on a tutorial I found, I did the following on [W3 Schools' Tryit Editor](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_op_in):

```
UPDATE Products 
SET ProductName = Unit 
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT * 
              FROM Products 
              JOIN Categories ON Products.CategoryID = Categories.CategoryID
              WHERE Categories.CategoryName = 'Beverages')
```

The SELECT statement by itself shows the correct (12) entries, but the UPDATE statement as a whole changes all (77) rows. Am I doing something wrong and can it be fixed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want a correlated subquery:

```
UPDATE Products
    SET ProductName = Unit
    WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM Categories 
                  WHERE Products.CategoryID = Categories.CategoryID AND
                        Categories.CategoryName = 'Beverages'
                 );
```

Comment: Curiously, this works. Could you explain, though, what does "SELECT 1" do?

Comment: `EXISTS` simply tests for the existence of a row.  `SELECT 1` is the simplest way to put a value in a row, so that is what I typically use for `EXISTS`.